# Filter data from html table parsed from json file

Tags: javascript, json

I have a html file that creates a table populated from a json file. Here's the sample:

http://prototypingtools.co/TEST/index.html

And here is the JSON:

http://prototypingtools.co/TEST/tools.json

I would like to include a filter on top of the page, where you can select which of the values are you interested in, and then show the results in the same table accordingly.

But I have no idea on how to do this (keeping it as simple as possible, without using plugins).

Any advice or pointers?

Comment: Filters would be checkboxes with possible values (they repeat in the JSON file).

Comment: So you want to pre-read the JSON file, populate check boxes under each heading and then filter when the user selects from the check box?

Comment: @rasmeister For example, in the "Runs On" column, posible options are 4 different. So I would like the user, when filtering, to select all the options that he/she wants using checkboxes, then apply/submit filters hitting a button, and the results will be shown according to the filter's configuration.

Filters will be a separate section that is not yet implemented.

Comment: So there are a number of isolated things that would need to be done. Reading the JSON to come up with the list of options, present those options in the UI, gather the user selections, filter and show the results. I would suggest you tackle each of those in turn, and as you encounter roadblocks ask for more specific assistance. Otherwise, you are asking someone to write your code for you which, on SO, typically means you won't get further responses since the question is too broad.

Answer (score 0):

I would put an input box where the user can enter a name, then add some script when the user hits a "Filter" button:

```
function filterByName(list, name) {
  return list.filter(function(item) {
    return (item.Name === name); 
  }
}
```